# Detect and count pattern in two lists in a dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, string, list

I need to detect and count how many patterns from UF_med variable are in UF_cadastral variable.

That is my dataset:

```
df = {'id': [1,2,3],
        'UF_med':[['SP', 'SC', 'PA'], ['SP'], ['AM', 'RJ', 'PA', 'RS']],
        'UF_cadastral': [['SP', 'PA'], ['SP'], ['AM', 'RS']]}

df = pd.DataFrame(df)
df.head()
```

Although I need to count the patterns, I tried at least  detect one pattern. However, the code only detect the first pattern of UF_med variable. I used that code:

```
df['Detect_Municipio'] = df.apply(lambda x: x['UF_med'] in x['UF_cadastral'], axis=1)
```

The result should be like that:

```
df = {'id': [1,2,3],
        'UF_med':[['SP', 'SC', 'PA'], ['SP'], ['AM', 'RJ', 'PA', 'RS']],
        'UF_cadastral': [['SP', 'PA'], ['SP'], ['AM', 'RS']],
        'Detect_Municipio':[2,1,2]}

df = pd.DataFrame(df)
```

Comment: What should be the output ?

Comment: df = {'id': [1,2,3],
        'UF_med':[['SP', 'SC', 'PA'], ['SP'], ['AM', 'RJ', 'PA', 'RS']],
        'UF_cadastral': [['SP', 'PA'], ['SP'], ['AM', 'RS']],
        'Detect_Municipio':[2,1,2]}

df = pd.DataFrame(df)

Answer (score 1):

```
  df['check']=[list(set(x).intersection(set(y)))\
  for x, y in zip(df.UF_med, df.UF_cadastral)]

  df['count']=df.check.str.len()





   id          UF_med   UF_cadastral     check     count
0   1      [SP, SC, PA]     [SP, PA]  [SP, PA]      2
1   2              [SP]         [SP]      [SP]      1
2   3  [AM, RJ, PA, RS]     [AM, RS]  [AM, RS]      2
```

Or just replacing `list` by `len` as follow:

```
df['amount']=[len(set(x).intersection(set(y))) for x, y in zip(df.UF_med, df.UF_cadastral)]
```

Result would be:

```
id            UF_med UF_cadastral  amount
0   1      [SP, SC, PA]     [SP, PA]       2
1   2              [SP]         [SP]       1
2   3  [AM, RJ, PA, RS]     [AM, RS]       2
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know exactly what you're trying to accomplish, but here are my best guesses:

Find overlapping lists in the two lists:

```py
df = {'id': [1,2,3],
        'UF_med':[['SP', 'SC', 'PA'], ['SP'], ['AM', 'RJ', 'PA', 'RS']],
        'UF_cadastral': [['SP', 'PA'], ['SP'], ['AM', 'RS']]}

output = [item for item in df["UF_med"] if item in df["UF_cadastral"]]
#output is [['SP']]
```

Find overlapping strings in all lists:

```py
df = {'id': [1,2,3],
        'UF_med':[['SP', 'SC', 'PA'], ['SP'], ['AM', 'RJ', 'PA', 'RS']],
        'UF_cadastral': [['SP', 'PA'], ['SP'], ['AM', 'RS']]}

uf_med = {item for sublist in df["UF_med"] for item in sublist}
uf_cadastral = {item for sublist in df["UF_cadastral"] for item in sublist}
output = [item for item in uf_med if item in uf_cadastral]
#output is ['AM', 'PA', 'RS', 'SP']
```

Find overlapping strings in same-index lists:

```py
df = {'id': [1,2,3],
        'UF_med':[['SP', 'SC', 'PA'], ['SP'], ['AM', 'RJ', 'PA', 'RS']],
        'UF_cadastral': [['SP', 'PA'], ['SP'], ['AM', 'RS']]}

output = [{item for item in list1 if item in list2} for list1, list2 in zip(df["UF_med"], df["UF_cadastral"])]
#output is [{'PA', 'SP'}, {'SP'}, {'AM', 'RS'}]
```

Answer (score 0):

Try changing

```
df['Detect_Municipio'] = df.apply(lambda x: x['UF_med'] in x['UF_cadastral'], axis=1)
```

to

```
df['Detect_Municipio'] = df.apply(
    lambda x: len(set(x['UF_med']) & set(x['UF_cadastral'])), axis=1)
```

The elements of your table are lists so you can use list intersection to get equivalent elements in those lists. Len gets you to the number of matches.